# Running a service in ALL RHCS cluster nodes

Tags: rhcs

I'm tryng to configure a service to be run in all nodes of a RHCS. I've tried placing the service without failover domain, but it appears to run only in one node

```
    <rm>
            <service autostart="1" name="rsync" exclusive="0" recovery="restart">
                    <script file="/etc/init.d/xinetd" name="RSync"/>
            </service>
    </rm>
```

Is there any option of doing that using **rgmanager** and **cman**?